# How do I create a table out of this twitteR output?

Tags: r, api, twitter

I want to create a table out of this twitteR output. Here is my code:

```
datafile <- read.csv(file="~Path/Workbook.csv")

data <-data.frame(lapply(datafile$recordName,as.character),stringsAsFactors = F)

x <- lapply(data[1:30], function(x) searchTwitter(x,n=5,since="2016-01-01"))

write.csv(x, file = "x.csv")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class "structure("status", package = "twitteR")" to a data.frame
```

I think I understand what is happening. Rows in the datafiles$recordName are producing different numbers of "searchTwitter" results (e.g., some record names show up more often on Twitter than others). What I would like to see in my CSV is [a table with a column with all of the records and repeating if necessary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMmNZ.png). I'm not sure how to achieve that.

I'm not sure if this is possible and anything will help. I'd be nice to be able to export this information as a clean table.

Here is a reproducible example:

R file:

```
library(twitteR)
consumer_key <- " "
consumer_secret <- " "
access_token <- " "
access_secret <- " "
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

datafile <- read.csv(file="/path/Workbook4.csv")
data <- data.frame(datafile$recordName, stringsAsFactors = F)
data <-data.frame(lapply(datafile$recordName,as.character),stringsAsFactors = F)
datafile

x <- lapply(data[1:4], function(x) searchTwitter(x,n=5,since="2016-01-01"))

x

write.csv(x, file = "x.csv")
```

Workbook4.csv

```
recordName,info
Spiderman 2,movie
Dodgers,mlb
blahblaheoi,random
Trump,pol
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It would help to see the contents of the CSV file or the `data` data frame.

Comment: Hi @neilfws, I added the CSV file and the .R file to my original post.